# Using a monad inside the IO monad

Tags: haskell, websocket

Is there something that is like the opposite of `liftIO`? I'm using websockets, and I want to be able to listen for messages from the server in a separate thread. Here's what I'm doing:

```
import Network.WebSockets
import qualified Data.Text as T
import Control.Monad.IO.Class
import Control.Monad
import Control.Concurrent
import Control.Applicative

printMessages :: WebSockets Hybi00 ()
printMessages = forever $ do
    resp <- receiveDataMessage 
    liftIO $ print resp

run :: WebSockets Hybi00 ()
run = do
    liftIO . forkIO $ printMessages
    forever $ do
      line <- liftIO getLine
      sendTextData . T.pack $ line

main = connect "0.0.0.0" 8080 "/" run
```

So `printMessages` listens for messages from the server and keeps printing them out. The problem is, `forkIO` expects a function that returns `IO ()`. Is there any way for me to run `printMessages` in the IO monad?

Comment: [`runWithSocket`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/websockets/latest/doc/html/Network-WebSockets.html#v:runWithSocket) perhaps? Generally, to get from a `MonadIO m` to `IO`, you need some `runXY` function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I'm understanding this right, the reason you want to receive messages in another thread is because the main thread will be waiting for user input to send.

From a look at [the documentation](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/websockets/latest/doc/html/Network-WebSockets.html), it seems like you'll have an easier time if you reverse the roles of the threads: receive in the main thread, and send asynchronously from the other.

Then you can use `getSink :: Protocol p => WebSockets p (Sink p)` to grab a sink before forking, which you can then use with `sendSink :: Sink p -> Message p -> IO ()` which lives in `IO`, avoiding the whole problem of mixing monads.

In other words, restructure your code to something like this:

```
sendMessages :: Sink Hybi00 -> IO ()
sendMessages sink = forever $ do
    line <- getLine
    let msg = textData . T.pack $ line
    sendSink sink msg

run :: WebSockets Hybi00 ()
run = do
    sink <- getSink
    liftIO . forkIO $ sendMessages sink
    forever $ do
      resp <- receiveDataMessage 
      liftIO $ print resp

main = connect "0.0.0.0" 8080 "/" run
```